# subset data in stargazer summary statistics

Tags: r, stargazer

I couldn't find the answer to this. I'd like to use stargazer for summary statistics. I would like my summary statistics to be subset by group, with group as a header. Any way to do this efficiently preferably within stargazer?

Comment: I added an example :)

Comment: I think your question was better in the previous version when you had the example :) Even better if you could include your data as code in the question!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my question and for the future readers. You can use `sumtable` via `vtable` package.

Just specify the group.

```
st(iris, group = 'Species')
```

More here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vtable/vignettes/sumtable.html